# MySite Profile Pic updates for two users not one

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile, my-site

When I am adding a profile picture for a user as an admin through the user's personal site, it is updating another user's picture and vise versa. It is only for these two accounts.

I have tried removing both pictures completely and running full crawls but same issue when i try to re add on either.

Is there anything you all can suggest I look into?

I am on SharePoint 2013 On Premise.

**EDIT**: Also, the profile picture also does not match the thumbnail.

These files do exist in the photo library.

Comment: Hi and you want to match profile pictures as the ThumbnailPicture imported fromAD?

Comment: Hi, the pictures are not imported from AD but rather added directly to the User Photos library or to the SharePoint Profile. I dont see where the picture can be added in an AD profile...thanks

Answer (score 0):

How did you upload the profile photo?

Make sure you upload the picture via user MySite: http://sp/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/person.aspx ->”Change your photo” in the top left corner of the page.

Then you can navigate to central administration->manage service applications->User Profile Service application->User Profile, search the relevant two accounts and edit their profile, check the “Picture” section. Or you can reupload the picture and check again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have tried both ways that you have suggested and still no luck. Any other thoughts?

Comment: In order to get the same updated in the User Profiles, I suggest you to run profile sync and check again.